# Strange behaviour of keras fit_generator method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a bigger dataset which contains up to 5M words. The total words won't fit in RAM, So I started using the generators. I trained my model using the fit_generator method.
While training for the first epoch the loss value starts from 4.7 at the end of the first epoch the loss value reduced to 1.7.
For the second epoch, the loss has to continue from 1.7 but it is not like that, again it starts from 4.7.
Can someone help out me to resolve this issue?

Here is my code:

https://gist.github.com/chatrapathik/fbd37f42984c6310dde200528f36c4f5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue, the training loss you see is a running mean, which is amn approximation of the real training loss, and in your case it seems some examples at the beginning produce a higher loss. Have you run your code for say, 10 epochs and see this effect consistently?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I run it for 50 epochs, But the loss value is not updated. Can you help out me to find out the issue here?

Comment: @chatrapathi You should update your question with the actual loss values you see.

Comment: Here I pasted loss values for 5 epochs. You can observe it here.

Epoch 1/100
424/423 [==============================] - 167s 394ms/step - loss: 1.8611 - mean_squared_error: 0.0054
Epoch 2/100
424/423 [==============================] - 161s 379ms/step - loss: 1.8650 - mean_squared_error: 0.0055
Epoch 3/100
424/423 [==============================] - 161s 379ms/step - loss: 1.8957 - mean_squared_error: 0.0055

Epoch 4/100
424/423 [==============================] - 161s 379ms/step - loss: 1.8583 - mean_squared_error: 0.0055
The same loss values apperas till the last epoch.

Comment: @chatrapathi I can only say that you model might be too simple for the data you have, maybe you need to have a deeper model, more layers, more neurons, etc, but that's not a programming problem. You have to tune your model to your data.

Comment: The same architecture of model is working with model.fit(), the loss rate is continuously reducing. But when I started using the model.fit_generator(), I am facing this issue. I tried it in both CPU and GPU, I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @chatrapathi Ok, that points a problem in the generator then, but still there are too many things that can go wrong (shuffling, the actual data order, etc).

Comment: We fixed this issue, here the problem is by default the fit_generator takes data shuffel=True, It causes the problem to us. By making shuffel=False, the loss value is reducing.